# Sharepoint online: 'new' sites derived from groups

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection

The 'new' sites offered as a transformation from groups might be easy to use for brand new users who have seen nothing else, but a pain for old sharepoint users. What I have noticed is that the new site, despite being a site collection does not appear in the list of site collections in admin center.

I see here ([Missing features on new sharepoint online sites](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/202842/missing-features-on-new-sharepoint-online-sites)) that there is a powershell script to turn the 'new' site into an old style 'site collection'. Did someone try it and does the converted site collection finally appears in the central admin interface?

Answer (score 1):

You have an option to control whether the new site that is created by your end users is a modern site or classic site. This can be done via Settings option in the SharePoint admin center.

[image]

I think just switching the user experience of a modern site to a classic site either via Powershell or GUI doesn't automatically make them appear in the list of site collection in the admin center.

Using the following Powershell commands you can see all SharePoint sites (including the ones attached to groups)

```
Import-Module "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline\Modules\SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline"
Connect-SPOService -url https://tenantname-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential (Get-Credential) 

Get-SPOSite
```

Answer (score 1):

Office Groups will not appear in the admin center. They are retrievable via PowerShell:

```
Get-SPOSite -limit All -Template "GROUP#0"
```

They have given guidance on how to disable Group creation by end users. It is a bit detailed but is straight forward and can be found [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-Office-365-Group-creation-4c46c8cb-17d0-44b5-9776-005fced8e618?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1).

Comment: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Template'. I am running this command in normal SPO/PnP modules. I can confirm there is no parameter called Template. Haven't tried connecting to Azure.