# Where is a list of modern SharePoint team sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, team-sites, modern-experience

The normal classic Team sites once created are listed on

- https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/SiteCollections.aspx
- Or a PowerShell command `Get-SpSite` lists all

But now when **Someone** not me, creates a new Modern Team site which is connected to Office 365 group. These sites are not listed on `SiteCollections.aspx` page, as well as PowerShell command, does not bring them. **So where on UI or command I can find them**?

I came across this limitation in the following use case

**Use case**: I am a SharePoint Online Admin, one of the Manager might have created a Modern Team site. now a request came to me to provide access permissions on this particular site for some user. I could nowhere find this Modern Site(*then eventually assuming it exists I fired Set-SpoSite command and set the user as owner, and it worked*).

If it was a classic site I would have found it on `SiteCollections.aspx` page, select it and manage owners from ribbon.

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/208953/sharepoint-online-new-sites-derived-from-groups/208965#208965

Comment: @HarryB You mean if I use PnP module and run `Get-SpoSite` command it will list all Modern Sites as well?

Comment: Yes, as admin center is not showing the group related sites - powershell is the way to go

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Get-SPOSite` will return modern sites along with the others. Modern sites will have a Template property of "GROUP#0".

So, to run a command that finds modern sites, add a filter on the Template property:

```
 get-sposite -Limit All | where { $_.Template -eq "GROUP#0"} | ft -Property Url,Template
```

> **Note**: One must have latest SharePoint Online Management Shell installed on his/her machine, i.e. `16.0.6323.1200`. You can find it
>   [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35588)

Comment: In `Connect-SPOService` command do you put SP Admin url? I checked with Get-SPOSite cmd unfortunately it does not return Modern Sites.

Comment: Yep, admin URL. When I run it on my tenant I can see all sorts of Modern sites.

Comment: Ok cool.. I got the problem. I was having older version of SharePoint Online Management Shell i.e. `16.0.4915.1200`. On installing the latest `16.0.6323.1200` version it worked perfect.

Comment: You can update your answer with a Note, that latest SPO management shell is must.

Comment: Just to add that I think if you are the SharePoint Admin only then you probably wont get Office 365 groups (modern site) as it requires exchange level privileges.