# Getting GROUP#0 site collections in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365-groups

Is there anyway to get a list of all the "hidden" site collections type GROUP#0 via powershell?

I noticed that modern team sites created by users do not appear in the central administration, and all the information and commands so far seem not to work.

I tried this without success (Filtering is not supported for property $_template)

```
Get-SPOSite -Filter {$_template -eq "Group#0"}
```

And this but it returns nothing:

```
Get-SPOSite | where {$_template -eq "Group#0"}
```

However, if I save the site collection in a variable (Get-SPOSite) and check it's "Template" property it is clearly a "GROUP#0".

Has anybody solved this?

Comment: Yep: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/213599/8056. You appear to be missing a dot, and check the comment about shell version. Also, string equality is case-sensitive, so be careful there.

Comment: It doesn't work. And I have a newer version of the shell (16.0.7115.1200). 

Anyway there is an interesting comment that says I need Exchange level privileges. My account only has SharePoint admin role. I took Exchange role as well but I still don't see the GROUP#0 sites

Comment: Ok, it's definitely permission matters. We tested it with the admin account and we receive all the site collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody is having the same issues in the future, please use the O365 admin account which has all access in order to retrieve all the site collections. The SharePoint admin account will only return the SharePoint site collections which are also visible via the central admin. There is no issue with the command.

Answer (score 0):

To get all Office 365 Group site collections, using the following PowerShell:

Get-SPOSite -Template GROUP#0